# Calculating weighted/unweighted GPA by reading text file into string/vector

Tags: c++, c, string, vector

I'm aware that there are many GPA calc questions in existence but I haven't managed to find one involving weighted and unweighted distinction.

I need to read the text file, input lines into a string or vector (not experienced with these), and parse the data (haven't done this before either) to calculate GPA and whether or not the credits are weighted. If the course is AP, the grade is weighted +1.0, if it is Honors, +0.5.

I'm pretty sure what I have so far is very wrong, but I'm trying to hash out the syntax for this type of operation.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){

        string data;
        vector<string> lines;
        ifstream myfile("Grades.txt");

        //test file open//
        if (!myfile){

            cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return -1;
        }
        //insert file text into vector//
        while (getline(myfile, data)){

            lines.push_back(data);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){

            if ((strlen(lines[i]) - 1) == 'A'){
                sum =+ 4;
            }
            else if ((strlen(lines[i]) - 1) == 'B'){
                sum =+ 3;
            }
            else if ((strlen(lines[i]) - 1) == 'C'){
                sum =+ 2;
            }
            else if ((strlen(lines[i]) - 1) == 'D'){
                sum =+ 1;
            }
            else {
                sum =+ 0;
            }
        }

    }
```

This is the text file's contents:

```
    Math A
    AP History C
    Chemistry B
    Honors Physics C
    Ethics A
```

Comment: Stealing the C tag because C has no standard namespace. Or namespaces for that matter. Mind you you can make namespaces in C with some really neat code, but that's a little off topic for this question.

Comment: `strlen(lines[i])` won't work. `strlen` works on a null-terminated character array. `std::string` typically contains a pointer to a null-terminated character array, but it itself is not a null-terminated character array. Instead `std::string` has a `size` function and a `length` function that both do the same thing: Give you the number of characters in the string. So `strlen(lines[i])` can be `lines[i].length()`. But this just gives you the length of the string and it looks like you want the last character in the string. See if your compiler has a `string::back` function you can use for that.

Comment: A side note: you can get rid of the `vector` if you parse the line and sum up the weights as you read the line in.

Comment: That said, it's really nice to see a beginning programmer using `string` and `vector` rather than muddling around with character arrays before they need to.

Comment: Thank a lot for the response. I removed the strlen() and am instead working with *myStr.rbegin by my instructors request. This has presented new issues, however....

Comment: Ignoring the fact that `myStr` has not been defined, [your rubber duck wants to know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) how you expect `char chr = *myStr.rbegin();` to behave before you read the information you need to parse from the file

Comment: A side note: you should not change a question this drastically after answers have started to roll in. More often than not, it makes the existing answers incomprehensible. Instead you should ask a new question based on the new code. In this case no answer really addressed your problem so so you get a bit lucky, but normally your edit would be reverted to preserve the integrity of the answers. In this case I recommend you edit the question again to restore the original code and then add your new solution as an addendum at the bottom.

Comment: will do, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know an awful lot about C++, but since you tagged this with C and your code contains some C constructs I'm going to pretend that I am qualified to answer it anyway.

Firstly, these lines are rather questionable:

```
system("pause");
return -1;
```

If you want to have the program wait (why?) the easiest way would probably be to just prompt for some input with getchar(). Also, don't return negative values from main(). The return should be between 0 and 127.

More importantly though, you're doing a few things that are not going to work at all. strlen() calculates the length of a NUL terminated C string. C++ std::string's are very definitely not NUL terminated strings and the result will be completely undefined. If you want to find the length of an std::string, you must call `std::string.length()`, which is much preferable anyway since the result doesn't need to be calculated. Also, you cannot use getline with an std::string either.

I actually wrote some code I was going to submit as a possible solution to your problem, but it was C code, and since I see you've removed the C tag from this question I won't include it.

EDIT: Ah, the heck with it, this is how I'd do it in C.

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define FILENAME "Grades.txt"

int main(void)
{
    struct stat st;
    char *tok, *obuf, *buf;
    FILE *fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r");

    if (!fp || stat(FILENAME, &st) != 0)
        err(1, "Failed to open/stat file %s\n", FILENAME);

    buf = obuf = malloc(st.st_size + 1lu);
    fread(buf, 1, st.st_size, fp);
    buf[st.st_size] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);

    int num_classes = 0;
    double grade = 0;
    while ((tok = strsep(&buf, "\n")) && *tok) {
        double weight = 1;
        if (strstr(tok, "AP"))
            weight = 2;
        else if (strstr(tok, "Honors"))
            weight = 1.5;

        int grd;
        switch(*(buf - 2lu)) {
            case 'A': grd = 4; break;
            case 'B': grd = 3; break;
            case 'C': grd = 2; break;
            case 'D': grd = 1; break;
            default:  grd = 0; break;
        }

        grade += weight*(double)grd;
        ++num_classes;
    }

    printf("The gpa is around %f\n", grade / (double)num_classes);

    free(obuf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(1)  Your code does not compile.  'Sum' is undeclared.  Please submit code that compiles.  (2)  The strlen call is trying to evaluate the length of a vector, not a string.  You then compare the string length to a letter.  You need to use the strlen as an index to a string before comparing it.